# How to fix UICollectionViewFlowLayout Transition not applying style to a cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

**I've created a pretty basic UICollectionView with a layout transition here:** https://github.com/aubrey/TestCollectionView

**There's a video of my issue here:** http://cl.ly/XHjZ

My issue is I don't know where / how to apply the shadow I'm adding to the cells. Whenever I add it, it doesn't apply correctly to the cell that's transitioned and hangs around after I transition back.

In my didSelectItemAtIndexPath method I tried applying the shadow here (no avail):

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

if (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout == self.smallLayout)
{
    [self.largeLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.largeLayout animated:YES];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}

else
{
    [self.smallLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.smallLayout animated:YES];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:NO];

}
}
```

I've also applied the shadow where I'm setting up my custom cell:

```
@implementation MyCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.myNumber = [UILabel new];
    self.myNumber.text = @"Data Array Didn't Load";
    self.myNumber.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.myNumber];

//       Shadow Setup
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15f;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.4f;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem – shadows always seem to cause a problem, don't they? If I understand correctly, the issue isn't that the shadow isn't appearing, but rather that the shadow isn't respecting the new bounds of the cell.

Typically, the best place to apply custom attributes like this one to a cell is overriding `applyLayoutAttributes:`. However, in this case, it's going to be tricky. This is because, unlike applying implicitly animatable properties belonging to UIKit, the shadow is set up on the CALayer of the cell, which means to get the animation of the shadow, you're probably going to need an explicit `CAAnimation`.

The problem with using an explicit animation is that there is no way to determine the duration of the animation at runtime. Additionally, say you wanted to transition from one layout to another without animation. There is no facility in the UICollectionView API to deal with that.

You've really hit an intersection of problems that the Apple engineers probably didn't foresee. I don't believe that you have many options. Overriding `applyLayoutAttributes:` and fiddling with an explicit animation would probably work, but has the limitations I mentioned earlier. Your best bet is probably to create a resizable `UIImage` that represents your shadow, and then add a `UIImageView` to the cell's view hierarchy so that as the cell grows and shrinks, so too does the image view with the shadow. I know that that's not a satisfying answer from a code perspective, but it's the most general-purpose answer that will lead to the least amount of frustration.